# Disk Utility message "Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required"

Tags: disk-utility, partition

Finder crashed on a external drive which caused an abrupt eject. I rand Disk Utility over the drive and the operation finished with the message:

> Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required

Its a FAT32 partition, it already existed, and it was not bootable so its not clear to me what required updating.

What does the message *"Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required"* mean? Or how can I determine the changes were made?

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message from Disk Utility is simply there to tell you it's checking the hidden EFI partition (if present) and updating *as necessary*. In your case it won't be necessary so nothing will be updated.

Disk Utility performs this extra step if you run a disk repair on a parent disk rather than on one of the partitions within that disk.